# Можно ли имитировать прокрутку пользователя до определенного места программно?

Tags: javascript

Суть такая. Есть страница и внутри неё есть iframe (предпросмотр того что будет).
Через библиотеку html2canvas делается скриншот блока внути iframe. Но там в iframe  подключается javascript код, который работает только если пользователь прокрутил до этого места. В итоге если пользователь не докрутил до этого места скриншот сохраняет пустоту.

Можно ли незаметно для пользователя (не меняя его положение на странице) заставить тот блок который ждёт докрутки до него исполниться полноценно?

Comment: А кто вам вообще разрешает прокручивать чужой iframe?

Comment: В этом iframe и есть код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените значение скрола на нужное положение (без плавных анимаций с быстрым возвратом обратно)

Comment: Не помогает. Только если задержаться на элементе 200-500 мил. сек, тогда работает.